# Qt получение ответа на get request

Tags: c++, qt, get, qtcreator, request

requests.h

```
#ifndef REQUESTS_H
#define REQUESTS_H

#include <QtNetwork/QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QtNetwork/QNetworkReply>

class Req : public QObject{
Q_OBJECT
public:
    QNetworkAccessManager *manager;
    QNetworkRequest request;
    QNetworkReply *reply;
    sendGet(QString Url);
private slots:
    void getReplyFinished(QNetworkReply *reply);
};

#endif // REQUESTS_H
```

requests.cpp

```
#include "requests.h"
#include <QTextCodec>
#include <QString>
#include <QObject>
#include <QTextCodec>
#include <QString>
#include <QMessageBox>

void Req::sendGet(QString Url)
{   manager = new QNetworkAccessManager();
    QNetworkRequest request;
    request.setUrl(Url);
    //user-agent
    request.setUrl(Url);
    request.setRawHeader("Authorization:", " OAuth AQAAAAAJlF7xAADLW8Sf6NXX-0ugtcoEeY_6dyM");
    request.setRawHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    request.setRawHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    reply = manager->get(request);//Получаем данные с сервера
    QObject::connect (
    manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
        this,   SLOT(getReplyFinished(QNetworkReply*))
    );
}

void Req::getReplyFinished(QNetworkReply *reply)
{   qDebug()<<"Task finished";
    QTextCodec* defaultTextCodec = QTextCodec::codecForName("Windows-1251");//Нужная нам кодировка
    QTextDecoder *decoder = new QTextDecoder(defaultTextCodec);
    QString HTML = decoder->toUnicode(reply->readAll());
    reply->deleteLater();
}
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "requests.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    Req req;
    req.sendGet("https://cloud-api.yandex.net/v1/disk/");
}
```

Не понимаю, почему getReplyFinished() не выполянется (точно в этом уверен, не выводит сообщение в консоль), никаких ошибок не выдает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QNetworkAccessManager` реализует запросы асинхронно. При вызове `req.sendGet` управление в `on_pushButton_clicked` возвращается сразу, и, соответственно, объект типа `Req` уничтожается до того, как в него придет ответ

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    Req req;
    req.sendGet("https://cloud-api.yandex.net/v1/disk/");
}
```

Необходимо создавать объект по указателю, а не по ссылке

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду вот так:     Req* req;
    req->sendGet("https://cloud-api.yandex.net/v1/disk/");

Comment: Потому что если я делаю так, то получаю, что variable 'req' is uninitialized when used here upd я понял, надо было инициализировать ее в нулевой поинтер

Comment: но в таком случае я получаю sig fault

Comment: ```Req* req = new Req();```

Comment: Прошу прощения, совсем голова не работает под вечер, не знаю, что творю, спасибо за помощь.